# How does one get the id from the globalState in a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Within the `vscode` extension context, there's `globalState`.  globalState is an ExtensionMemento object, and at runtime while debugging I can see that it has a private `_id`.

How do I obtain the id? I've tried:

```
 context.globalState.get<string>("id");  
 context.globalState.get<string>("_id");
```

...but each return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When the extension is activated, the current extension context is passed as argument. You may use the `context.extensionPath` to find `package.json` and parse it.

```js
import * as Path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    var extensionPath = Path.join(context.extensionPath, "package.json");
    var packageFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(extensionPath, 'utf8'));

    if (packageFile) {
        var packageId = packageFile.publisher + '.' + packageFile.name;
        console.log(packageId);
    }

//......... rest

}
```

Answer (score 0):

context.globalState["_id"]